# Does `Product` implies `reflection`?

Tags: scala, reflection

Does the use of `Product` implies `reflection`?

More precisely: Does `Product.getClass.getDeclaredFields` use reflection?

Comment: `Product` no, `getClass.getDeclaredField` yes. Could you please be more clear about your question? Where are you using this, why are you using this? why the use of reflection seems like a problem for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getClass` is method which came from JVM part of Scala and it exists for every reference type, it has nothing in common with `Product`. It will return `Class[T]` object, representing reference run-time class.